# OpenSSH Server won't start on orangepi/linux

Tags: linux, ssh, networking, dpkg, openssh

I am currently doing some testing with an Orange Pi. After doing an update on a fresh install it seems as though the ssh server is no longer able to start itself, and I'm not able to manually start it either. Purging and reinstalling openssh-server still leaves me with the same error after reinstall

Error:

```
setting up openssh-server (1:7.2p2-4ubuntu2.6) ...
Failed to validate path /var/run/sshd: Bad file descriptor
Job for ssh.service failed because the control process exited with error 
code. See "systemctl status ssh.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript ssh, action "start" failed.
ssh.service - OpenBSD Secure Shell Server
loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/ssh.service; enabled;vendor preset: enabled)
Active: activating (auto-restart) (result: exit code) since WED 2018-11-21 11:01:38; 59ms ago
Process: 6423 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/sshd -t (code=exited, status=255)
Failed to start OpenBSD Secure Shell....
ssh.service: Unit Entered Failed state.
ssh.service: Failed with result 'exit code'
dpkg: error processing package openssh-server (--configure):
sub-process installed post-installation script returned aroor exit status 1
errors were encountered while processing: openssh-server
```

ssh.conf  :

```
# ssh - OpenBSD Secure Shell server
#
# The OpenSSH server provides secure shell access to the system.

description     "OpenSSH server"

start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [!2345]

respawn
respawn limit 10 5
umask 022

env SSH_SIGSTOP=1
expect stop

# 'sshd -D' leaks stderr and confuses things in conjunction with 'console
log'
 console none

pre-start script
    test -x /usr/sbin/sshd || { stop; exit 0; }
    test -e /etc/ssh/sshd_not_to_be_run && { stop; exit 0; }

    mkdir -p -m0755 /var/run/sshd
end script

# if you used to set SSHD_OPTS in /etc/default/ssh, you can change the
# 'exec' line here instead
exec /usr/sbin/sshd -D
```

for whatever reason the config file isn't making the directory

Comment: Add the contents of `/etc/init/ssh.conf` to your question.

Comment: The message complains about `/var/run/sshd`. Does this path exist? Did you make changes to the distribution-provided setup or config?

Answer (score 2):

Alright, I played around with it myself for a bit. It turns out that the filesystem likes to clean /var/run/sshd on boot. My fix for now is that I made a bash script to make that directory on boot and then start the ssh service. It seems to work right now although there probably was a faster way I'm just not familiar with.